# Confusion in retrieving null values using Joins

Tags: mysql, sql, database, join

There are two tables in a database say table1 and table2 .. table1 has columns ip_address and application_name whereas table2 has columns ,ip_address, avg_cpu , ram_utilization , date

I want to retrieve all the ip_address,avg_cpu (average cpu utilzation) for the date 2012-03-01 that host application 'my_system' ...if a particular ip_address doesn't have avg_cpu value ... null should be returned for that ip_address .. what modifications should i do to the below query to get expected result ...am confused as this is the first time i'm new to joins

```
SELECT 
  `table1`.`ip_address`,
  `table1`.`application`,
  `table2`.`avg_cpu`
from  
  `table1`
   right outer join `table2` ON `table1`.`ip_address`=`table2`.`ip_address`
where
   `table2`.`date`='2012-03-01'
    and `table1`.`application`='My_System'
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm sure if I understand your question, but it sounds like you might want to try "left outer join", which will include rows for which the join predicate does NOT match... in that case, the values from the right side of the join will be NULL

Comment: on trying left outer join one of the ip_address that didn't have avg_cpu utilzation value in table2 was not displayed ... that ip_address is present in table1 and not in table2

Comment: As HLGEM mentions below, the problem is in your where clause.  The Left Join will include a row for the IP address which is missing in table2, but then it gets filtered out by your where clause, because the date is null and thus not equal to '2012-03-01'.  Try the clause "(`table2`.`date`='2012-03-01' OR `table2`.`date` IS NULL) and ..." to see what I mean.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure you need an outer join? If so, then your query should look like this:

```
SELECT 
  `table1`.`ip_address`,
  `table1`.`application`,
  `table2`.`avg_cpu`
from  
  `table1`
   left join `table2` ON `table1`.`ip_address`=`table2`.`ip_address` and `table2`.`date`='2012-03-01'
where
  `table1`.`application`='My_System'
```

note that I changed rigth join for left join, and moved the table2 condition to the ON section (this is required for left/right joins, otherwise they work as inner joins)

Answer (score 0):

If I understandyour needs correctly I think this will work:

```
SELECT
   `table1`.`ip_address`,
   `table1`.`application`,
   `table2`.`avg_cpu` 
FROM     `table1`    
LEFT OUTER JOIN `table2` 
    ON `table1`.`ip_address`=`table2`.`ip_address` 
        AND `table2`.`date`='2012-03-01'     
WHERE `table1`.`application`='My_System'
```

LIke @RyanHenning, I think you mean a left join not a right join so I have adjusted the code accordingly.  Note that even though you had the words right outer join in your original, you effectively did not have an outer join as you put specific conditions in the where clasue that had to be met by the table on the left side of the join. I also think you may find this link helpful in understanding why the where clause was incorrect. 
http://wiki.lessthandot.com/index.php/WHERE_conditions_on_a_LEFT_JOIN